# Button Alignment

Tags: android, button, alignment

I made a camera layout where two buttons existed.A `click` button and a `share` button.

Problem is i want to make align this buttons in same view,but i can not.

this is my code for button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click"
    android:layout_gravity="left" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonShare"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Share"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
```

[image]

But i want the `click` button will be the same place where the `share` button stay ...

Comment: Put them inside Horizontal LinearLayout

Comment: Ofcourse Both of them inside one Horizontal LinearLayout

Comment: Its good habit to read before development, [Luksprog](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11132188/646806) provided the solution to you,its solved your issue but for further info refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) in deep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have them in a `LinearLayout` along the other view(with the "Camera demo" text). But without seeing the complete layout file you could wrap them in another layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonShare"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Share"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

From you image, your parent layout is using LinearLayout with vertical orientation. Therefore each view you added to it will place one by one in vertical direction.

If you want to put two buttons in same row, you have to use RelativeLayout to wrap these two buttons. And place the child to the right and left of the RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonShare"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Share" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Click" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Click" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonShare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="Share" />
        </RelativeLayout>

should have one more RelativeLayout as parent of all....
```

[image]

which I made as compelte..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Click" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonShare"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Share" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand layout in better way follow this [Layout](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/07/android-layouts-linear-layout-relative-layout-and-table-layout/)

here. and according to your question better use Relative Layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" //to assign botton to bottom of layout
     >
```